# Maximum function nesting when extending twig template for sonata admin

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I am using the following template to extend specific widget

```
{% use 'SonataAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block textarea_widget %}
  {% spaceless %}
  <div class="textarea_widget">
    <textarea {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>{{ value|raw }}   
    </textarea>
  </div>
  {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock textarea_widget %}
```

The main problem is that it's reaching maximum function nesting. There must be some infinite recursion when extending template. When i copied code from extended template everything works. Any idea how to make this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this error i needed to create form_admin_fields.html.twig file in app/Resources/SonataAdmin/views/Form with the following content:

```
    {% block textarea_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
    <div class="textarea_widget">
        <textarea {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>{{ value|raw }}   </textarea>
    </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
    {% endblock %}
```

So there is no necessity to use or extend template just redefine some block.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably caused by xDebug that you must configure with `xdebug.max_nesting_level` parameter. Default is 100 but I usually upgrade it to 1000 to be quiet.

On a Debian, it's in `/etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`.

Official doc about this parameter:

> xdebug.max_nesting_level Type: integer, Default value: 100
>
> Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection.
>   The value of this setting is the maximum level of nested functions
>   that are allowed before the script will be aborted.

Comment: And You think that increasing limits is a good solution? I have tested this and 1000 is still not enough and 10000 will probably too. I don't believe that core developers made such bug so it must be another issue  related with templates inheritance

Comment: It's well-known that 100 is too low when using a heavy framework with templating. I change it to 1000 cause Symfony2 were buggy in earlier version, and needed high value for tests. Of course, if you need more, it seems that you have a problem...